# SQL query to join and verify if there's no corresponding rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently doing this query, however, I'm always getting a result where there should be none, because there's a corresponding row.

```
select `likes`.*, `likeshistory`.`like_id`, `likeshistory`.`instagram_id` from `likes` join `likeshistory` on `likes`.`id` = `likeshistory`.`like_id` where (`finished` = '0' and `active` = '1' and `banned` = '0') and `instagram_id` not in ('2') limit 1
```

Basically I want to select one "likes" that has no "likeshistory" for (instagram_id = 2)

[likeshistory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHQDT.png)

Thank you!
William

Comment: Can you please post sample data and structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`.  The purpose of the query is clearer:

```
select `likes`.*, `likeshistory`.`like_id`, `likeshistory`.`instagram_id`
from `likes` l
where not exists (select 1
                  from `likeshistory` lh
                  where l.id = lh.`like_id` and
                        (`finished` = '0' and `active` = '1' and `banned` = '0') and lh.instagram_id not in ('2')
                 );
```

If any of the conditions in the subquery (except the correlation clause) are on `likes`, then those should be in the outer query.